# Showing proper balance amount displaying MySQL rows in descending order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that is supposed to show deposits, withdrawls, and balance.  I am summing the deposits and withdrawls to get the balance.

The query and display works ok when `ORDER BY` date `ASC`.

However, I wish to order by `DESC` and this is causing issues with the display of balance.  Here is an example.

```
Date   Deposit   Withdrawl   Balance
Jan 2            $2000       -$2000
Jan 1  $5000                 $3000
```

As you can see I would want the Jan 1 balance to be 5000 and the Jan 2 balance to be 3000.  I'm stuck on a good way to solve this.  At first, I simply created a column for balance and inserted the balance as the row was being written.  But this caused problems when a single row was updated.

Any help appreciated!  Thanks.

Here is the code I'm working with.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bankaccount_transaction WHERE bankaccount_id = '$id' ORDER BY ID DESC ".$pages->get_limit()) or die(mysql_error());

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
$date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($row2['date']));

if ($row2['deposit'] > 0){
$deposit = $row2['deposit'];
$newdeposit = number_format($deposit,2);
$newtotal += $deposit;
}else{
$newdeposit = '';
}

if ($row2['withdrawl'] > 0){
$withdrawl = $row2['withdrawl'];
$newwithdrawl = number_format($withdrawl,2);
$newtotal -= $withdrawl;
}else{
$newwithdrawl = '';
}

display table

}
```

Comment: Show code where balance is calculated.

Comment: how do you calculate balance result? could not you leave asc while doing calculations (like you did before) and when printing results order by desc?

Comment: bojan, how would I do that, almost need 2 while iterations to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
     , SUM(y.deposit)-SUM(y.withdrawal) Balance 
  FROM transactions x 
  JOIN transactions y 
    ON y.bankaccount_id = x.bankaccount_id
   AND y.date <= x.date
 WHERE x.bankaccount_id='$id' 
 GROUP 
    BY x.date 
 ORDER 
    BY Date DESC;
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70242/1)

Comment: Is this inside the while iteration?

Comment: This is the whole query. It's all you need.

Comment: Seems to be working but I need to get "WHERE bankaccount_id = '$id' " in to the query, but it gives me an error no matter where I put it.

Comment: $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT x.*, SUM(y.deposit)-SUM(y.withdrawal) AS balance FROM bankaccount_transaction x JOIN bankaccount_transaction y ON y.date <= x.date GROUP BY x.date WHERE x.bankaccount_id='$id' ORDER BY ID DESC") or die(mysql_error()); this gives You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE x.bankaccount_id='14' ORDER BY ID DESC' at line 1

Comment: I've got it.  WHERE x.bankaccount_id='$id' AND y.bankaccount_id='$id'

Answer (score 1):

Without more information about your problem, I'd say you want to store the balance in the database with each transaction. Otherwise, to compute the balance at any point in time, or current balance, you always have to load and sum every row in the database.

Comment: I tried storing the balance in each row as it was inserted.  However, if a deposit/withdrawl was editted somewhere in the middle, the new balance would change and all the other rows that came after would not be aware of this new balance.

Comment: Without knowing more about the problem, I disagree. As a general rule, do not store data that can be easily calculated on the fly from other data.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
SELECT 
    m.`date`, 
    m.`deposit`, 
    m.`withdrawal`,
    SUM(t.`deposit`) - SUM(t.`withdrawal`) AS `balance`
FROM `bankaccount_transaction` m 
    JOIN (
            SELECT 
                `date`,
                `deposit`,
                `withdrawal`
            FROM 
                `bankaccount_transaction`
        ) t ON t.`date` <= m.`date`
GROUP BY 
    m.`date`, 
    m.`deposit`, 
    m.`withdrawal`
ORDER BY m.`date` DESC
```

I'm trying to see if I can start a fiddle.

Edit: 
Here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d040/9

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help!